# Setting 4 column for the category layout does not work?

Tags: magento

I am trying to set 4 product columns on the category page and to remove the right sidebar. This is what I added to my local.xml:

```
 <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <remove name="right"/> 
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

It removes the content of the right sidebar, but in the HTML it still has the right sidebar div, just without any content. This should be gone imho. In the list.phtml file I set the columns like this:

```
$this->setColumnCount(4);
```

Whats missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want side bars? or no side bars? Why don't you use 1column layout?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
<label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
               ---
               ---
               ---
            </block>
            <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>  <!-- Add this line -->
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

similarly for following also add    `<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>`

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>

</catalog_category_layered>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>  <
        </reference>

</catalog_category_default>
```